# Нейронные сети - смещения

Tags: машинное-обучение, нейронные-сети, deeplearning4j

Не могу понять принципы смещения, пока изучил только смещения с помощью сигмоидной функции, да и в принципе только с ней и работал, но знаю что это основано только на  логический ответ ДА или НЕТ, как же работает смещения, изучения больших выходных данных?

В интернете натыкаюсь только на сигмоидные нейросети (т.е. с сигмоидным изучениям и результатом)